# Android Studio and SVN - Not every File/Folder will commit

Tags: android, svn, android-studio, commit

I use Android Studio IDE with Subversion and I commit the Android Project.

But not all files will commit, because if I do a checkout in a other directory, many folders and files are missing like "res", "activity.xml"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for the answer.

I solved the problem by this way:
Right click on a folder/file->Subversion->Add

After that, svn detects the change.

Comment: Right click file/folder>Subversion> [other than revert, all options are unavailable for newly created file]. i have to add the file to svn by accessing svn from windows context menu of the file in windows explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that those items were added to [`svn:ignore`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) versioned property since they don't need to be version-controlled. See ["How to manage projects under Version Control Systems"](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23393067-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems).